# Is there a difference between "genetic cross regulation" and "crosstalk"?

Tags: gene-expression, gene-regulation

What is the difference between genetic cross regulation and crosstalk? I'm a physics major and learning about bioinformatics now. So it might seem trivial to many but from the article "[Wanner BL. Minireview. Is cross regulation by phosphorylation of two component response regulator proteins important in bacteria? J Bacteriol 1992; 174:2053-8.](https://jb.asm.org/content/jb/174/7/2053.full.pdf)" I could not find a quantitative way to separate these two kind of gene regulations. Also, I would appreciate if anyone can suggest me something to read for further knowledge on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You may find it helpful to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. 

Comment: When learning about a new area I have found it helpful to start with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/). Wikipedia can also be a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms exist called MOOCs that offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two that I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Comment: I have never heard of “cross regulation” and it seems to be a term invented by the author of the review you cite, and which has never gained common currency. “Cross-talk” is not a specific regulatory mechanism, but a vague general term for the reciprocal interaction between two systems. As my Irish friend would say, if I wanted to get there, I wouldn’t start from here.

Comment: @David I have come across this term while studying some articles on systems biology. And those were very recent. One such article is "Zhou, X., Franklin, R.A., Adler, M., Jacox, J.B., Bailis, W., Shyer, J.A., Flavell, R.A., Mayo, A., Alon, U., and Medzhitov, R. (2018). Circuit Design Features of a Stable Two Cell System. Cell 172, 744-757.e17." So, you are probably right. The author may have coined the term "cross regulation"